# Efficient list data structure

Tags: c, performance, list, data-structures, skip-lists

I need a list-type data structure to implement in a project. Actually it doesn't necessary have to be some kind of list, but it has to be fast and I'm going to use to it to constantly insert/delete/retrieve data (other data structures) from it. I might insert something, search, insert again, delete, search again and so on, so actions are sort of random.

I found skip-lists the fastest so far, what is there faster than that?

Comment: How are you searching? What are you indexing by? Your question boils down to "I want a fast data structure" but we need more details about your access pattern to give a real answer.

Comment: I'm indexing by uniques strings. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great deal depends on your language of choice. C gives you the greatest control over your final data structure, and you will end up with one of the fastest implementations. With, of course, a very easy time shooting yourself in the foot. Rather badly. Python abstracts a lot of list data structure, and I find it is consistently fast, but I'm not stressing it too terribly either.

I would suggest a check of freshmeat for prebuilt C libraries that you can repurpose for your task. Perhaps wikipedia's page on skip lists will point you towards more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Data structures are a deep subject that requires a decent grounding in big O notation and exactly what it means when we talk about "speed" and "efficiency" or you will not be able to make an objective comparison. Finally, everything has trade offs. Pick a data structure that most closely models both your data, and how you intend to manipulate it. If you're tasks are rather random, step back into the design phase and ask your self how you can refine what happens before it gets to the data structure. That is, get your algorithm hammered out, and then pick a data structure to complement it.

Comment: C is the language I'm using. The project is tested by runtime, so the faster it gets to do all those operations, the better. It's not important memory wise.

Answer (score 0):

A [hashtable](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hash_table)/hashmap/dictionary sounds like what you want. For example, [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the [BTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)